# C++ function runs 'string' type arguments through strlen(), saves new values to dummy class instance, passes dummy class to new function. Why?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to write a program to sort wineries by name and by rating (high to low) using a doubly threaded linked list in C++. There is a class List and class Winery. Each instance of Winery stores name, location, acres, and rating.

In main, a function 'insertWinery' is called that takes the four arguments: name, location, acres, rating. This function makes a new instance of Winery,  *w, and it edits "name" and "location" using strlen. It then saves the numerical value of these two arguments in new variables called "nm" and "loc" which it copies into the dummy '*w,' and then passes *w into the function 'insert' in list.cpp, which actually does the insertion.

I don't understand why the strings are being changed into numerical values. I could just iterate through the characters in the string and alphabetize the different wineries and then use a loop to find the correct spot in the list to insert the new winery by name, so why would I want to make it a number instead? Of course it's easier to search numerically but I don't see what the number has to do with the correct alphabetical order of the wineries, and there may be wineries that have the same number of characters in their names.

I'll include a copy of the function 'insertWinery' here:

```
static void insertWinery(char *name, char *location, int acres, int rating)
{
    Winery *w;
    char   *nm  = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    char   *loc = new char[strlen(location) + 1];

    strcpy(nm, name);
    strcpy(loc, location);
    w = new Winery(nm, loc, acres, rating);
    wineries-> insert(*w);
    delete[] nm;
    delete[] loc;
    delete[] w;
}
```

The insert function that *w is being passed to is of type list:

```
void List::insert(const Winery& winery)
{
// code to be written
}
```

If any more information is needed please let me know, I don't think more than this is necessary though. I just want to know why the values of name and location are being changed to numbers before *w is passed to List::insert(const Winery& winery). I need to write the insert function but I don't know what to do with those values or how I'm supposed to run a name thread through the list when I have random string lengths instead of names now.

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated, thank you

EDIT: Winery constructor:

```
Winery::Winery(const char * const name, const char * const location, const int acres, const int rating) :
    name(NULL),
    location(NULL),
    acres(acres),
    rating(rating)
{
    if (this->name)
        delete[] this->name;
    this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(this->name, name);

    if (this->location)
        delete[] this->location;
    this->location = new char[strlen(location) + 1];
    strcpy(this->location, location);
}
```

Comment: why `strcpy` in C++? use `std::string`

Comment: You can entirely sidestep a lot of issues by using `std::string` along with `std::list`

Comment: Thanks very much. My instructor provided the file in which this particular function and main were included, with instructions to edit nothing in the file, so as far as the code posted above it must stay as is or it may be ineligible for a grade. Again thank you for taking the time to reply!

Comment: @BabaSvoloch - What does the `Winery` constructor look like?  What does the `insert` function do?  If the constructor or the `insert` function calls code that may throw an exception, your teacher's advice is crap (even wrong), as you would never get to the lines with the `delete[]`, thus causing a memory leak.  If this is the case, your code is the prime example of why a string class should be used.

Comment: The insert function inserts a winery into the list of wineries. Each winery has a nextByName pointer and a nextByRating pointer,

Comment: @BabaSvoloch - That doesn't answer my question.  If there is any code that can throw an exception in either the Winery constructor or the `insert` function, you have a memory leak.  Your teacher probably never told you that, but it is very easy to write code that may throw an exception without you knowing it (due to inexperience).  For example `new` can throw an exception.  That's why it is counter-productive for a teacher to say to you "don't use std::string", and at the same time not warn you about the exception issue that can render those calls to `delete[]` absolutely useless.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just got a new computer and the trackpad sucks ~_~; it's doing weird things. I didn't mean to send that, it was only the beginning of my answer. We spent a decent amount of time going over memory leaks and the Winery constructor seems to reflect this function operationally. I'm going to go ahead and add the Winery constructor above, thanks for taking the time to look this over!

Comment: Your instructor provided this code? It's terrible. Not having a go, just be aware if or when you code C++ in the real world, you need to do it differently.

Comment: More helpful, perhaps, would be the inclusion of an explanation concerning -why- you consider it to be terrible and the provision of an alternative. No, my professor did not provide the constructor. I am very new at this.

Comment: @BabaSvoloch: That explanation was the first comment: use `std::string`. Your instructor is doing you a disservice. The correct way to avoid memory leaks is to have one class per memory resource.  For strings, that class should be `std::string`. For double-linked lists of integers, `std::list<int>`. The exact reason why won't fit in a single comment, but the summary is that you don't have to deal with partial failures which is very very hard to get right. `insertWinery` as written has two leaks for that reason.

Comment: @BabaSvoloch - Your `Winery` constructor can throw an exception, and the calls to `new[]` in your `insertWinery` can throw an exception, thus you have potential memory leaks.  What you are being taught, hate to say it, is wrong, just plain wrong.  If on the other hand, this code is provided to you to show you purposefully bad code, and then later how to correct it, then that's a different story.  However, I doubt that.  What would be fascinating is if your teacher knows him/herself how to fix the problems we've pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why the strings are being changed into numerical values.

That's not what your code is doing. The following code:

```
char   *nm  = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
```

allocates new memory, with the *number of characters* being the length of `name` plus 1. It is not converting the name into a number at all. Then the `strcpy(nm, name);` copies the bytes from the parameter `name` into the newly allocated memory pointed to by `nm`.

Your code probably does not actually need to do this copying. But it's impossible to tell for sure without knowing what the `Winery` constructor is doing.